# Magento Admin - Default Shipping

Tags: php, magento

When creating a new order within the admin area can we default a shipping option to automatically be selected?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean selection in the `"shipping methods"` block during order creation, that it isn't possible (without customizations), because it depends from product list, shipping address options and will calculated after clicking on link `"Get shipping methods and rates"`.